# In cryptography, a Caesar cipher Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In cryptography, there is a Caesar cipher. I am trying to build one in Ruby, but I don't know how to use capital letters in my range `('a'..'z').to_a.join`. How do I use capital letters?

```
class Caesar

def initialize(shift)
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a.join


  i = shift % alphabet.size


  @decrypt = alphabet
  @encrypt = alphabet[i..-1] + alphabet[0...i]
end

def encrypt(string)
  string.tr(@decrypt, @encrypt)
end

def decrypt(string)
  string.tr(@encrypt, @decrypt)
end
end

cipher_1 = Caesar.new(1)
s = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!'
puts s
s_encoded = cipher_1.encrypt(s)
puts s_encoded
pudaats = cipher_1.decrypt(s_encoded)
puts pudaats
```

**OUTput**

> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!
>
> A nbo, b qmbo, b dbobm: Pbobnb!
>
> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!

**But i need Out Put**

> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!
>
> B nbo, b qmbo, b dbobm: Qbobnb!
>
> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!

Comment: Looks like homework to me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa: The question is that he's not getting capital letters transposed.

Comment: @RyanBigg That is a statement, not a question.

Comment: @sawa It's pretty clear that he's seeking help to correct the output of his program to correctly transpose letters. Please be kind to those who are ESLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   LOWER_CASE = ('a'.ord .. 'z'.ord)
    UPPER_CASE = ('A'.ord .. 'Z'.ord)

  def shift(c, by)
        byte = c.ord
        if LOWER_CASE.include?(byte) then
            ((((byte - LOWER_CASE.min) + by) % 26) + LOWER_CASE.min).chr
        elsif UPPER_CASE.include?(byte) then
            ((((byte - UPPER_CASE.min) + by) % 26) + UPPER_CASE.min).chr
        else
            c
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here lies within what you've defined as the alphabet.

```
a..z # ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Notice here that there's no capital letters. The only letters that are being transposed are the lowercase ones. Therefore you will need to change your range to include uppercase characters as well:

```
alphabet = (("A".."Z").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a).join
```

Then you will get the correct result.